# Makefile run same target multiple time concurrently with different option

Tags: docker, makefile

I wish to build multiple docker images through my makefile. I have a make target looking like this:

```
docker:
    docker build -t service1:latest -f ./service1/Dockerfile .
    docker build -t service2:latest -f ./service2/Dockerfile .
    ...
```

To gain time, I want to run them in parallel, so I wanted to update my makefile like this:

```
docker:
    docker build -t $(SERVICE):latest -f ./$(SERVICE)/Dockerfile .
```

And calling it with something which would look like this:

```
make -j=2 SERVICE=service1 docker SERVICE=service2 docker
```

But obviously it does not work since there is multiple issues with this.
I was thinking to use the pattern %, but I am not quite sure how to achieve this cleanly.
What would be the right way to achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

You could write something like this:

```
IMAGES = \
     service1 \
     service2

all: $(IMAGES)

.PHONY: $(IMAGES)
$(IMAGES):
    docker build -t $@:latest -f $@/Dockerfile .
```

The `.PHONY` directive is necessary because otherwise it will find the directory named `service1` or `service2` and decide that the target does not need updating. `.PHONY` tells it to ignore this and build the target in any case.

Using this `Makefile`, if I run `make -j` it spawns to build processes in parallel.

---

While this works, I'm not sure that `make` is really the right tool for the job. The idea behind `make` is that it will only rebuild those things that need to be rebuilt, saving time if only a few things have been modified.

In this situation, `make` doesn't really have any way to make that sort of decisions.

Since you want to rebuild everything every time, you might be better off with a simple shell script and `xargs`:

```
#!/bin/bash

seq 2 |
xargs -iSERVICENUM -P0 docker build -t serviceSERVICENUM -f serviceSERVICENUM/Dockerfile .
```

Or if your services aren't actually named in a numeric sequence:

```
#!/bin/bash

SERVICES='
foo
bar
'

xargs -iSERVICE -P0 docker build -t SERVICE -f SERVICE/Dockerfile . <<<$SERVICES
```